# Mac Outlook 2016 Inline Response Formatting

Tags: ms-office

It seems like a recent update to Mac Outlook 2016 broke the formatting of replying inline.  Up until recently (the last 2-3 weeks) when I would reply with inline questions/comments, it would separate my edits from the indented, original email.  Now, I don't see it creating this separation; my edits just blend in (with the same level of indentation) as the original message.

Am I crazy, am I missing an option in the preferences menu to fix this myself, or is this actually a regression that other people are seeing as well?

Comment: You are not crazy.  Microsoft really is this bad at user experience.

Comment: This is insane. What kind of company makes an email client where you can't reply to emails properly?